# Diagnosing errors inside newcommands

Tags: macros, errors

When I need to use something repeatedly within a document, I make my own command. E.g.:

```
\newcommand{\notification}[2]{      % line 2
    Hello #1, your #2 pie is ready. % line 3
}                                   % line 4
```

Then I can use it in the document like so:

```
\notification{Mr. White}{pumpkin}   % line 6
```

However, if I make some mistake while coding the `newcommand`, it does not say "l.3"; it will say "l.6". See in the example below (I have added an extra "&"):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\notification}[2]{
        Hello #1, your #2 & pie is ready.
    }
\begin{document}
    \notification{Mr. White}{pumpkin}
\end{document}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\notification #1#2-> Hello #1, your #2 &
                                         pie is ready. 
l.6     \notification{Mr. White}{pumpkin}
```

In this case, it is simple to diagnose, because I can quickly recognize the line `Hello #1, your #2 pie is ready.` and find it with a search; however, in more complex documents, `Hello #1, your #2 pie is ready.` might appear dozens of times, so I don't know where to look; or the reported error displays other code (which I will assume is underlying TeX code) not actually included within any of the code I wrote, so the messages seem of little help.

What are some general steps one can take to aid in the identification of the source of errors of this type?

Comment: Something like `\foo #1…#9->` is always the expansion of a macro, so you have to look not only at the line number given by `l.<nr>`, but also at the definition of the macro. But if you are searching for a something like symbolic TeX debugger: You are not the only one, but there isn't such a tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think of this less as a LaTeX issue and more as a work flow one:

- Whenever I define a `newcommand`, I test it on a few samples before using it in a real world document. Keep a scratch file if you're writing a lot of them so you don't get a bad aux file contributing to confusion.
- If I edit an existing`newcommand`, I edit only one at a time. So if an error sneaks in, I know where it came from.
- Reuse `newcommands` and put comments next to them if they require particular packages or TikZ libraries. I have something like 30 macros that I created years ago for my thesis. I make special ones for particular documents, but reusing code obviously minimises the chances of an error getting in.
- I know this is a not-so-helpful answer, but it does avoid problems and I never get errors from badly coded macros.

Comment: A useful simple tool for debugging macros is to set `\errorcontextlines=10` so that TeX shows more expansion context and it's sometimes easier to guess at what macro went wrong.

Comment: Oooh. Nice! You should throw that in as an answer!

Comment: You can add it to your answer. It's just the first trick one should use before going to the big guns such as `\tracingmacros=1`.

Comment: Nah, I'm maxed out today anyway. The best I'd get is 15 rep. ;)


Ahem. I mean, *credit where credit is due*, eh?

Comment: FWIW, ConTeXt sets `\errorcontextlines = 5` in the format...it does make debugging so much easier.